# MongoDb - Add new document if field doesn't exist, add default fields, without hitting the database twice

Tags: mongodb

In the instance of a new user registering... how can I check if that user exists, create a document, and add default fields.... without hitting the database twice?

usernames should be unique in a collection, no duplicates allowed

I can't use `findAndModify({username: bob})` with `upsert: true` because a user could modify a preexisting record with username bob.

The only way I can think of is 
`users.insertOne({username: bob}).then(function(doc) { user.findAndModify(doc._id) { $set add default fields })` but I'm hitting the database twice which is lame.

Comment: If you intend to mix this with "potential updates" then [`$setOnInsert`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/) will affect on create. Other things such as `$inc` would then apply only to matched documents. Depends on whether there is an intention to update anything, or whether this is just for inserts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not do the insertOne with the username and all the additional fields? Assuming you have a unique index on the the username field, you'll get an exception you can handle.